# Android: How to improve the performance of my camera

Tags: android, image, performance, size, android-camera2

I develop an android camera app! I use camera2 to implement the camera module! The problem is that when I take a picture with it, the size of the image is too high, something about 9MB!!! So my gallery is too slow! What is the reason of it?

I test it in different cell phones, the size of images are different, but still too high!! I tried `photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, out);` this code to reduce the size, but the quality of image is too important to me, so I don't want to reduce the resolution! Here is my camera code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Size previewsize;
    private Size jpegSizes[] = null;
    private TextureView textureView;
    private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder previewBuilder;
    private CameraCaptureSession previewSession;
    private static VirtualFileSystem vfs;
    ImageButton getpicture;
    ImageButton btnShow;
    Button btnSetting;

    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureview);
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(surfaceTextureListener);
        getpicture = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.getpicture);
        btnShow = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btnSetting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_setting);

        btnSetting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Setting.class));
            }
        });

        btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Gallery2.class));
            }
        });

        getpicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getPicture();
            }
        });

    }

    void getPicture() {
        if (cameraDevice == null) {
            return;
        }
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            if (characteristics != null) {
                jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
            }
            int width = 640, height = 480;
            if (jpegSizes != null && jpegSizes.length > 0) {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            }
            ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
            List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(2);
            outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
            final CaptureRequest.Builder capturebuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            capturebuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            capturebuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            capturebuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener imageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);                     

                        Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, null);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, out);
                        save(out);
                        photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, 120, 120, false);
                        btnShow.setImageBitmap(photo);

                        save(out);
                    } catch (Exception ee) {
                    } finally {
                        if (image != null)
                            image.close();
                    }
                }

                void save(ByteArrayOutputStream bytes) {

                    File file12 = getOutputMediaFile();
                    OutputStream outputStream = null;
                    try {
                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file12);
                        outputStream.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            if (outputStream != null)
                                outputStream.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("takepicture");
            handlerThread.start();
            final Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(imageAvailableListener, handler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback previewSSession = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureStarted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, long timestamp, long frameNumber) {
                    super.onCaptureStarted(session, request, timestamp, frameNumber);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    startCamera();
                }
            };
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    try {
                        session.capture(capturebuilder.build(), previewSSession, handler);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                }
            }, handler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            String camerId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(camerId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            previewsize = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(camerId, stateCallback, null);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener surfaceTextureListener=new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            openCamera();
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        }
    };
    private CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback=new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice=camera;
            startCamera();
        }
        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(cameraDevice!=null)
        {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }
    }
    void  startCamera()
    {
        if(cameraDevice==null||!textureView.isAvailable()|| previewsize==null)
        {
            return;
        }
        SurfaceTexture texture=textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        if(texture==null)
        {
            return;
        }
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(previewsize.getWidth(),previewsize.getHeight());
        Surface surface=new Surface(texture);
        try
        {
            previewBuilder=cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        previewBuilder.addTarget(surface);
        try
        {
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    previewSession=session;
                    getChangedPreview();
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                }
            },null);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
    void getChangedPreview()
    {
        if(cameraDevice==null)
        {
            return;
        }
        previewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        HandlerThread thread=new HandlerThread("changed Preview");
        thread.start();
        Handler handler=new Handler(thread.getLooper());
        try
        {
            previewSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewBuilder.build(), null, handler);
        }catch (Exception e){}
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private File getOutputMediaFile() {


        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MyCamAppCipher1"+"/" + mTime + ".jpg");

        mediaFile = new File("/myfiles.db"+"/" + mTime + ".jpg");
        return mediaFile;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this piece of code, you're selecting the first available resolution, which usually is the highest one.

```
        int width = 640, height = 480;
        if (jpegSizes != null && jpegSizes.length > 0) {
            width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
            height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
        }
```

Aside from doing what you're saying, which is reduce image quality by calling `photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, out);`, your alternative is selecting a smaller camera resolution, by iterating the `jpegSizes` array and selecting a lower resolution.

Take into account that to do so you should use relative compares (i.e. width >= minWidth), or find the middle resolution, but always selecting one of the ones available in this array. Notice that this array will vary from phone to phone (i.e. it depends on the camera characteristics).

For example, let's say that you need a minimum of 3M pixels (2048x1536). You could have the following code:

```
int width = Integer.MAX_VALUE, height = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < jpegSizes.length; i++) {
    int currWidth = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
    int currHeight = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
    if ((currWidth < width && currHeight < height) &&  // smallest resolution
        (currWidth > 2048  && currHeight > 1536)) {    // at least 3M pixels
        width = currWidth;
        height = currHeight;
    }
}
```

Notice that there are two conditions:

- in the first line, we're looking for the smallest possible resolution (always smaller than the previous one; notice also the initial values for `width` and `height`, `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which means that at least the first value will always match this condition)
- in the second line, we're making sure is **at least** 3M pixels

So, all combined this code will select the smallest resolution possible, at least 3M pixels.

Finally, you may add a fallback condition: if no matching resolution is found (i.e. `width` and `height` are `Integer.MAX_VALUE`), select the first one as you're currently doing.

Comment: I didn't understand how to select a smaller camera resolution, could you explain it more please?!?

Comment: Basically, you have to iterate the array (a common `for` loop) and check if the candidate matches your expectations. I'll update the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a camera app with camera2 too and saving images into disk is nearly immediate, even with 12 or 15 Mb picture size (no need of compressing to 50%). When you say your gallery is slow... are you loading full size images into thumbnails? Are you displaying full size images? Try to load small pictures to your thumbnails and display.

Comment: I use this code in my gallery for thumbnail: BitmapFactory.Options 
 options.inSampleSize = 16;
final int THUMBSIZE = 64;
                try {
                    bmp = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options),
                            THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } Is it good?!?!!??

Comment: I do not see anything wrong in this code. Maybe you could try to use a bigger inSampleSize. Are you doing this in a thread?

Comment: Yes, I do it in a thread! But I do not save the thumbnails, should I save it!?!

Comment: Well it depends... if creation of a thumbnail is very time consuming, then yes, you can try to save the thumbnails and load them directly.

Comment: If I save it, does it improve the performance of my gallery?!

Comment: You will not know until you implement it ;)

Comment: Yes you're right! Thank you so much for your help!! :)